# Find polynomial : $P(x)=x^3+ax^2+bx+c$

Tags: polynomials, roots

Find all polynomials in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is of the form $P(x)=x^3+ax^2+bx+c$ which has $a, b, c$ as its roots.

Is [my answer below](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2405791) correct?

Comment: I don't see any errors in your answer, and [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x3%2Bax2%2Bbx%2Bc%3D(x%E2%88%92a)(x%E2%88%92b)(x%E2%88%92c)) agrees as well!

Comment: @Toby Mak. Thank you !

Comment: Well done! Perhaps, so that the question is not left unanswered, move your answer in the question to a separate answer. Then we can vote on it and you can accept it.

Comment: There is another solution, very ugly to write down with exact radicals, which is $x^3+0.565198 x^2-1.76929 x+0.638897=0$

Comment: @Raffaele is that in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$?

Comment: @lhf. Okay. I'll move my answer in the question to separate answer. I will not accept my answer because other may give better answer.Thank you :)

Comment: @MANMAID  No, no. It isn't. Just for fun :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Vieta's formulas,

$$a+b+c=-a,\\ab+bc+ca=b,\\abc=-c.$$

Then if $c\ne 0$,

$$ab=-1$$
$$c=-2a-b$$
$$-1-(a+b)(2a+b)=-2a^2+2-b^2=b$$ and

$$2a^2b^2=(2-b-b^2)b^2=1.$$

The last equation has no rational roots and the only remaining option is $c=0$, giving

$$2a+b=0,ab=b$$

with the two solutions $a=b=0$, and $a=1,b=-2$.

Comment: Thank you very much, Yves Daoust

Answer (score 3):

$x^3+ax^2+bx+c = (x-a)(x-b)(x-c)=x^3-(a+b+c)x^2+(ab+bc+ca)x-abc$

so $a=-(a+b+c)$, $b=ab+bc+ca$, $c=-abc$

Case 1 : $c=0$ so $b=ab$ then $a=1$ or $b=0$

if $a=1$, we get $(a,b,c)=(1,-2,0)$

if $b=0$, we get $(a,b,c)=(0,0,0)$

Case 2 : $c\not=0$ so $ab=-1$ then $-1+c(a+b)=b$ ---[1]

Since $a=-(a+b+c)$, so $c=-2a+\frac{1}{a}$

substitute $c=-2a+\frac{1}{a}$ and $b=-\frac{1}{a}$ in [1]

we have $1+(a-\frac{1}{a})(2a-\frac{1}{a})=\frac{1}{a}$, then $(a-1)(2a^2(a+1)-1)=0$

If $2a^2(a+1)-1=0$, then $2a^3+2a^2-1=0$, by Rational root theorem, a $\not \in \mathbb{Q}$

so $a=1$, we get $(a,b,c)=(1,-1,-1)$

Answer : $P(x)=x^3$, $x^3+x^2-2x$, $x^3+x^2-x-1$